# 1px of the link isn't being underlined or hovered over

Tags: html, css

What is the fix for this...

[image]
[image]

Here is the CSS:

```
        .post a{
        color:black;
        text-decoration: underline;
        font-size:13px;
        line-height: 1.3;
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .post a:hover{
        color:white;
    }
```

Here is my HTML:

```
    <small>on April 20th in <a href="#">Marijuana</a> tagged <a href="#">Drugs</a>, <a href="#">Science</a>, <a href="#">Herb</a></small>
```

Comment: This looks like the IE6 bug described [here](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/italicbug-ie.html). Can you confirm that this problem occurs only in IE6?

Comment: Does it only happen with italicized text?

Comment: Using Chrome (this could be a browser issue) I only see the 1px problem on the 's' in 'Drugs' and I'm guessing it's because the italic styling pushes the pixel into the view of the comma. I don't see a problem with 'Marijuana' as your image suggests.

Comment: The problem goes away when I get rid of 'italic'

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't see a problem there. But instead of `text-decoration` you can use `margin-bottom` and try to give the anchor-elements some padding.

Comment: If you do not see the problem, your answer will not be relevant.

Comment: Thanks thepriebe for catching that, yep its the italic styling. Right on, Smoke on.